# Closing a scene in javafx

Tags: javafx

I'm learning javafx and I have a problem.
I'm building an interface with a border pane and a menu bar at the top and when I click on the items I want scenes to be loaded on the center of the border pane. That seems to be working alright. I want to add a button to close the scene but I can't make it work.
See below the code.

```
stage = primaryStage;
stage.setTitle("My Program");
BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

Menu menuFile = new Menu("File");
MenuItem load = new MenuItem("Load");
MenuItem save = new MenuItem("Save");
....

BorderPane sp = new BorderPane();
sp.setStyle("-fx-background: #FF0000;");

Button btn = new Button("Close");
btn.setPrefSize(200, 20);
btn.setLayoutX(200);
btn.setLayoutY(200);

sp.getChildren().add(btn);
load.setOnAction(e -> pane.setCenter(sp));

btn.setOnAction(e -> ???????????????????);

scene1 = new Scene(sp);

scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 500);  
stage.setScene(scene);   
stage.show();
```

I was wondering if it's something that I can do and what code I should put instead of the question marks.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
btn.setOnAction(e -> pane.setCenter(null));
```

to clear the border pane content, or

```
 btn.setOnAction(e -> stage.hide());
```

to close the entire window